# Table in the middle of the page when responsive doesn't stay between header and footer

Tags: html, css, angular

How my page looks (header + table + footer): https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6tdO.png

How my page looks (header + table + footer) when responsive (smaller width): https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsGkc.png

There are 2 main problems:

- table goes over the header,
- footer goes under the header, somehow ignoring the table, and goes over the table.

The main problem is that I want to fix the table to be between the header and the footer, which I've done, but the table to still be in the middle of the page, which is my problem.

What I think might be the problem:

1. the method I use to position the **table** in the **middle** of the page:

```
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

2. the method I use to position the **footer** at **the bottom** of the page:

- when no responsive:

```
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
```

- when responsive:

```
position: relative;
```

I want to mention that if I don't try to position the table in the middle of the page, that means I comment on the code from `What I think it might be the problem` point 1. => the page looks good: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgf8S.png

So, because of this, I've tried to apply different methods to position the table in the middle of the page but it didn't work.

I've tried multiple methods, even putting limitations on my table and footer, which means setting the top and height of them but it still doesn't work quite well.

Comment: Hi David, that happens when you position your elements with absolute, which I consider as bad practice, use flexbox instead where the header and footer are fixed while the middle content takes as much space as possible. If you post plunker, people will more likely respond with code example.

Comment: I've tried the flexbox, but from what I remember it didn't work for me. Anyway, I will try to read the docs and give it a try again because I saw a lot of people talking about flexbox, which they described as a new and efficient method to position things. And I will read what plunker is, but is it something like stackblitz, where you put code and see the result?

Comment: yes, stackblitz is good too :)

Answer (score 0):

position:relative; By giving, the position absoulte you use in the table works, the parent container must be relative.

Sample:

```
<div class="container">
<table>
</table>
</div>
```

```
.container {
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.container table {
   position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

You can solve it more easily with display properties, not just positions.

I hope it helped.

Comment: I've tried this before when I was searching to solve my problem, but it doesn't work. I even tried it again right now and this is how the page looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/72pyh.png

Comment: can you share the code and style code screen  or .container table { display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; margin:auto; width:100%; height:100%; }

Comment: Sure, but can you tell me what exactly to show? Because I don't know what else to show you compared to what I have in the body of the question.

Comment: Since I don't know the exact code, I guess this will solve the situation. .container table { display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; margin:auto; width:100%; height:100%; }

Comment: Sorry, but still doesn't work. I did put, what I think it's important (code), in the question. I can give you more code but tell me what exactly you want to see. Later I will try to post it on Plunker so you will see the entire code and the result live.

Comment: What does the structure look like as html code?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkBwO.png

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, I did what @Andrej told me to.

I used flexbox to structure the entire body, which means a fixed header and footer and the 'rest' will take as much space as possible, even when responsive and without any side-effects. I did see many good examples on google, simply if you type 'flexbox fixed footer' for instance and you will see how easy it is. The specific site that helped me was this one: https://dev.to/akshay_rajput/keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-using-flexbox-4a6f.

Thank you for the answers.